# Deleting file from dam (publish server) will delete automatically from author server?

Tags: adobe, aem

I've implemented code to delete the uploaded files from DAM storage[CRXDE] , I've one doubt will the code delete the file from author server too? If not how to delete the file simultaneously from author as well as 4 publish server. 
With the below code , the file is getting removed from publish CRXDE.

Code:

```
AssetManager assetManager = (AssetManager) resourceResolver.adaptTo(AssetManager.class);
String damUtil=DamUtil.assetToBinaryPath(selectedFileName);
assetManager.removeAssetForBinary(damUtil);
```

Answer (score 2):

To replicate changes from publish instances back to author instances you can use a mechanism called *reverse replication*. Normally, you *replicate* changes from an author to a publisher. This is the *reverse* operation to this, hence *reverse replication*.

Since it is a big topic I would like to point you to the official Adobe documentation for more information on how to configure *reverse replication*:

[Official (reverse) replication documentation by Adobe](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/deploy/configuring/replication.html#Replicating%20from%20Publish%20to%20Author)